# What are all the options for \tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents

There is no documentation for this command anywhere.
I'm using the beamer-document-class and even the documentation for that doesn't show an exhaustive overview of all the options of the command.

Comment: Regarding `beamer`, isn't section 10.5 of the `beamer` manual just what you're asking for? Edit: in the standard classes the macro doesn't have any options.

Comment: You assert, "There is no documentation for [`\tableofcontents`] anywhere." The user guide of the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package provides a nice overview of the (admittedly fairly limited) capabilities of the standard, i.e., unmodified `\tableofcontents` command. Incidentally, I'm not sure what you mean by "all the options of the command" -- the command takes exactly **zero** options.